# Como criar uma função que retorna multiplos elementos em uma lista - REACT

Tags: javascript, array, react

Estou começando a estudar React agora, e preciso manipular uma lista de objetos.

Tenho a minha lista de transações e sei que preciso mudar o estado dela pelo meu setTransacoes (código abaixo)

Por exemplo, tenho um campo select no meu form que contem os meses em questão. A minha intenção é saber como pego o valor do select (mês em questão) inserido pelo usuario e faço uma função que, baseado no número de parcelas, que será um input do tipo select, percorra o array de meses, encontre o mês em questão e adicione para os meses subsequentes.

```
Ex: export function App() {
     const [transacoes, setTransacoes] = useState([]); \\lista das transações
     const [transacaoName, setTransacaoName] = useState('');
     const [valor, setValor] = useState(0);
     const [parcelas, setParcelas] = useState('');
     const [mes, setMes] = useState('');

     const meses = ['janeiro', 'fevereiro', 'março', ...]

     function handleSubmit() {

       const item = {
         id: crypto.randomUUID(),
         transacaoName,
         valor,
         parcelas,
         mes
       }

       setTransacoes([...transacoes, item]}

       \\ Adicionar função que baseado no select de parcelas escolhidas pelo usuario
       adicione essa transação aos proximos.
       
       \\exemplo: se o usuario escolher o mes de janeiro e a parcela ele escolher o valor 2, 
       eu preciso criar no meu array de transacoes dois objetos: 
       
       **ficaria assim meu array de transacoes:
       {
         transacaoName: 'qualquer uma',
         valor: 500
         mes: 'Janeiro',
         parcelas: '2'
       }
       {
         transacaoName: 'qualquer uma',
         valor: 500
         mes: 'Fevereiro',
         parcelas: '2'
       }**
     }
     
     return (
       <form onSubmit={handleSubmit()}>
         <input type="text" name="transacaoName" label="transação" />
         <input type="number" name="valor" label="transação" />
         <select name="mes">
           <option value="valor1">Janeiro</option>
           <option value="valor2">Fevereiro</option>
           <option value="valor3">Março</option>
           ...
         </select>
         <select name="parcelas">
           <option value="1">1</option>
           <option value="2">2</option>
           <option value="3">3</option>
           ...
        </select>
       </form>
     )
   }
```

O código não está certinho, eu acho, porque fiz aqui rapidinho só pra tentar explicar a dúvida, então ignorem os erros, mas se puderem me ajudar na lógica, eu ficaria agradecido. Sei que é uma dúvida bem boba, mas gostaria muito de aprender.

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, substituindo o trecho apresentado por um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Queira consultar a [help] e respectivos links para um melhor proveito do site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podes usar o método indexOf() para encontrar o índice do mês. Depois usas um ciclo com o número de parcelas para inserir os itens.

```
function handleSubmit() {
  var mes_idx = meses.indexOf(mes);

  for (var i = 0; i < parcelas; i++) {
    const item = {
      id: crypto.randomUUID(),
      transacaoName,
      valor,
      parcelas,
      mes: meses[(mes_idx + i + 1) % 12]
    }

    setTransacoes(prev => [...prev, item]);
  }
}
```

Comment: perfeito, ajudou muito!! Porém ainda preciso de mais uma ajuda... Se eu seleciono qualquer mês, o primeiro item do array não aparece o valor do mês em questão... A segunda dúvida seria para se caso ele selecionasse o mês de dezembro, como faria para aparecer novamente os meses de janeiro, fevereiro etc, porque da forma como está, ele apenas adiciona a quantidade, tipo, 5 itens no array. Porém eu precisava da informação do mês em questão

Comment: Resposta editada.

Comment: Muito obrigado cara, você ajudou demais! Respondeu exatamente a forma como eu precisava! Obrigado pela disponibilidade e ajuda...